# How to write to DocumentFile in Android programmatically?

Tags: android, file, documentfile

Android API has [`DocumentFile` class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html). This class has [`canWrite()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html#canWrite()).

Suppose I called this method and it returned `true`. Also suppose this object was representing "raw" file.

Now how can I do what it said I can?

Namely, how to write "Hello world" text into that file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Namely, how to write "Hello world" text into that file?

It is not necessarily a file.

To write to the document identified by that `DocumentFile`, call `getUri()` on that `DocumentFile` to get the `Uri` to the document. Pass that to `openOutputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`. Then, write to the stream, `flush()` the stream, and `close()` the stream. Basically, once you get the `OutputStream`, from there ordinary Java I/O takes over.

Comment: `java.io.File` is also not necessary a file.

Comment: @Dims: It is, insofar as any given `File` object either points to a file or is invalid. A `Uri`, instead, can point to lots of things. For example, `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043114/how-to-write-to-documentfile-in-android-programmatically/42043137` is a valid `Uri`. It does not point to a file on any client device.

Comment: Okay, I see this.